# can iPhone detect digital signal through microphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, converters, microphone

I'm working on a project which needs the iPhone to detect a small set of voltage data (two different values of voltage representing 0 and 1 respectively). My initial thought is to detect it through microphone, but I'm not sure if iPhone would be able to detect these signals since it contains no info of frequency. I searched in iOS Developer resources and on google, but nothing clear about this problem. Can anyone help me with this question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by detect digital signals? Are you talking about system sounds? If you could just clarify a bit then that would be awesome.

Comment: Thank you Pavan. To be specific, in this transmission system, a sensor would like to send two voltages which represent 0 and 1 to iPhone through microphone. (the sent signal is like __一__一__ )

Comment: Oh fantastic, I can tell you an easy way to do this but it would require the use of the headphone jack or to create your own hardware thats then registered with apple's MFi program. For demonstration and testing purposes you can use the headphone jack for now. If its a simple on and off signal then you can get good results with the headphone jack instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual problem when trying to use an audio signal as digital signal input is that it is [high-pass-filtered to avoid offsets](http://blog.faberacoustical.com/2010/ios/iphone/iphone-4-audio-and-frequency-response-limitations/) (long term pressure changes which could destroy the dynamic range of the soundcards Analog-to-Digital converters). This means you will get only the changes of the digital signal (like "clicks"). Actually you will be better of the higher frequency your signal has, but it will be non-trivial to process it well then (this was what ordinary modems did very well).

If you can control the digital signals sent as sound (or to the microphone jack), make sure they are modulated the signal with one or more tones, like a morse transmitter or modem. Essentially you want to use your iPhone as an [Aucoustic Coupler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem#Acoustic_couplers). This is possible, but of course a bit computationally expensive considering the quite low bandwidth.

Start by using some dirt simple modulation, like [1200-1800 Hz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDC-1200) and make an FFT of it. There's probably [some reference implementation for any sound card out there](http://www.matthew.at/mdc/) to get started with.

There have been some cool viruses recently that was said to be able to jump air-gaps, they used similar techniques as this one.

If you still really want a DC (or slowly changing digital signal), check out a [solution using a separate oscillator](http://lea.hamradio.si/~s57uuu/scdsp/CheapChop/cheapchop.htm) that is [amplitude-modulated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation) by the incoming signal

Comment: Hi claj, thanks for your respond. But I still have doubts here, because in my case, the signal I need to detect is combinations of two different values of voltage. It has no info of frequency. Is the iPhone able to detect this signal under this circumstances?

Comment: Do you mean it changes from, lets say 0.6 V to 0.3 V and from 0.3 V to 0.6 V? What is the information carrying part? is it the change of the level or the level itself? The soundcard could probably detect correctly if the level of the voltage rise or falls.

Comment: Yes, it is like change voltage from 0.6V to 0.3V or 0.3V to 0.6V. And the change of the voltage itself represents different information. So without the frequency, the soundcard could still detect the rise or falls of voltage,right? Could you please tell me how to fetch these input voltage data? which framework should I refer to ? I only worked with audio data by recording them using AudioUnit. But I don't know how to directly fetch the data from headphone jack as voltage.

Comment: Audiodata is an array of numbers, representing the current (≈ voltage)-level that the microphone created when the sound was recorded (or how much the loudspeaker should be pushed in or out). The numbers in the array of numbers represent the voltage-level that moment. The number needs to be scaled somehow. But if there's an Highpass-filter before the ADC, the constant part of the level will "disappear", only the difference will be seen. (You will see the derivata of the level). If the voltages goes up, there will be a positive spike at that moment of rise, and vice versa.

Comment: Oh, I see. So actually I can directly use the audio data recorded to represent the digital signal if the voltage I sent contains only two values, right? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, the audio pressure equals electrical levels equals digitized value in the audio buffer.

Comment: Thanks! It works when I use my headphone to record voltage with a tone. However, when I use the cable to connect my Mac and the signal generator, it seems that the simulator uses the microphone on my Mac to collect data instead of the headphone jack. Do you know how to set it to receive data from headphone jack instead of microphone on Mac? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Apple -> System Preferences -> Sound -> [Tab] Input -> ... chose what seems decent. Maybe you need to connect a four-pole 3.5 mm plug (the one on headssets) to get the tone in via line in.

Answer (score 1):

as per our discussion, it seems you want to send a digital signal to the iphone. Now there are two main ways to do this.

1. Either sign up to Apples MFi hardware licensing program which allows you to create hardware for the iPhone. [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). Or,
2. There is an easy way to do this but it would require the use of the headphone jack. For demonstration and testing purposes you can use the headphone jack and if its a simple on and off signal then you can get good results with the headphone jack overall and might not require to create yourself a piece of hardware. Here's a link to that [Grab sensor data and send it through the iPhone headphone jack](http://www.creativedistraction.com/demos/sensor-data-to-iphone-through-the-headphone-jack-using-arduino/)

In fact, using the headphone approach is not as bad as it may sound, you can receive a nice signal if needed. Anyway, it will suffice for your purposes. Have a look what [this guy is doing.](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2011/01/project-hijack-uses-iphone-audio-jack-to-make-cheap-sensors/) I suggest you start with the video demonstration to get an overall idea of this approach.

**UPDATE 1**
Have a look [at this link](http://www.instructables.com/answers/could-the-iPhones-headphone-jack-be-used-as-an-in/). People are using the headphone port to detect voltage. The reason this works is because the iPhone jack is a combination earpiece (output only) and microphone (input only) connector. The microphone input is a single wire, with common ground to the earpieces.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pavan, it is what I am looking for. I'll check the article now to see if it works for me. :)

Comment: Hi Pavan, it seems that the project in the linked article uses an external hardware Arduino to modulate the data from sensor. Since I don't have such hardware, does that mean that the headphone jack itself cannot detect voltage itself?

Comment: You can use the headphone jack as an input device, this can only be done with manipulating the voltage and then decoding the signal. Have a look at the update in my post to see what the guys are talking about and how the'yre going about their implementation. Goodluck man